# Karaf 4.2.7 logger output missing

Tags: logging, log4j, apache-karaf

After updating Karaf to 4.2.7 the loggers are not working correctly.
(Before the logs worked fine)

The loggers are still found by karaf.
 Using log:list:

```
Logger                                                                       │ Level
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼──────
AccountInformationLogger                                                     │ DEBUG
ROOT                                                                         │ WARN
RepairServiceLogger                                                          │ DEBUG
UploadPerformanceLogger                                                      │ DEBUG
org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.jcr.JcrNode                                    │ ERROR
org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.jcr.node                                       │ DEBUG
org.apache.karaf.cellar.event.LocalEventListener                             │ FATAL
org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.RegisterWebAppVisitorWC              │ FATAL
org.ops4j.pax.web.extender.war.internal.UnregisterWebAppVisitorWC            │ FATAL                                           
useraccess                                                                   │ INFO
usertracking                                                                 │ INFO
```

But the output in the karaf.log ist just:

```
Nov 28, 2019 10:05:37 AM org.apache.karaf.main.Main launch
INFORMATION: Installing and starting initial bundles
Nov 28, 2019 10:05:38 AM org.apache.karaf.main.Main launch
INFORMATION: All initial bundles installed and set to start
Nov 28, 2019 10:05:38 AM org.apache.karaf.main.lock.SimpleFileLock lock
INFORMATION: Trying to lock /home/example/webapp/drive.assembly.trunk/lock
Nov 28, 2019 10:05:38 AM org.apache.karaf.main.lock.SimpleFileLock lock
INFORMATION: Lock acquired
Nov 28, 2019 10:05:38 AM org.apache.karaf.main.Main$KarafLockCallback lockAcquired
INFORMATION: Lock acquired. Setting startlevel to 100
```

My org.ops4j.pax.logging.cfg seems like this:

```
log4j.rootLogger=WARN, out, osgi:*
log4j.throwableRenderer=org.apache.log4j.OsgiThrowableRenderer

# user access
log4j.logger.useraccess = INFO, useraccess

# FILE appender
log4j.appender.out=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.out.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.out.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} | %-5.5p | %-16.16t | %-32.32c{1} | %X{bundle.id} - %X{bundle.name} - %X{bundle.version} | %m%n
log4j.appender.out.file=${karaf.data}/log/karaf.log
log4j.appender.out.append=true
log4j.appender.out.maxFileSize=50MB
log4j.appender.out.maxBackupIndex=5

# FILE appender for user access
log4j.appender.useraccess=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.useraccess.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.useraccess.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} | %-5.5p | %-16.16t | %-32.32c{1} | %X{bundle.id} - %X{bundle.name} - %X{bundle.version} | %m%n
log4j.appender.useraccess.file=${karaf.data}/log/useraccess.log
log4j.appender.useraccess.append=true
log4j.appender.useraccess.maxFileSize=50MB
log4j.appender.useraccess.maxBackupIndex=5
...
```

What is the reason why there is only a short part of the log printed in the karaf.log?

Edit:
tried with following org.ops4j.pax.logging.cfg:

```
log4j.rootLogger=debug, stdout, R

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

# Pattern to output the caller's file name and line number.
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n

log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=example.log

log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=100KB
# Keep one backup file
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=1

log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %t %c - %m%n
```

But the log (log:display) is also empty.

With [this log4j2 example](https://github.com/apache/karaf/blob/master/assemblies/features/base/src/main/resources/resources/etc/org.ops4j.pax.logging.cfg) the log is printed (log:display) and it's also in the log file. Is there a problem with karaf 4.2.7 and log4j1?

Comment: Are you using pax-logging? Which _backend_? (log4j1, log4j2, logback)

Comment: the karaf uses the maven dependencies pax-logging-api (wich includes log4j version 1.2.17) and pax-logging-log4j2. I want to use the log4j1 backend (if possible)

Comment: If you're using pax-logging-log4j2, then you have wrong configuration - for log4j1. Check configuration provided by Karaf itself.

Comment: Thanks you are right. I used log4j2 in the startup.properties instead of pax-logging-service.